# Is "from ... import ..." sometimes required and plain "import ..." not always working? Why?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-import

I always thought, doing `from x import y` and then directly use `y`, or doing `import x` and later use `x.y` was only a matter of style and avoiding naming conflicts. But it seems like this is not always the case. Sometimes `from ... import ...` seems to be *required*:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52)
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__version__
'6.1.0'
>>> im = PIL.Image.open("test.png")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("test.png")
>>>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

If not, can someone please explain me the mechanics behind this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For submodules, you have to explicitly import the submodule, whether or not you use `from`. The non-`from` import should look like

```
import PIL.Image
```

Otherwise, Python won't load the submodule, and the submodule will only be accessible if the package itself imports the submodule for you or if some previous code has explicitly imported the submodule.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot! I guess the easiest way to find out, if I need an explicitly import, is to try out, right?

Comment: Pretty much. It is up to the package itself whether it provides its (known) submodules as attributes. `os` is an example of a package that does: `import os` makes `os.path` available.

Comment: Do you also know, what the reason for some developers is, to *not* provide submodules as attributes? It seems this makes it a little bit more cumbersome for the users of the module...

Comment: Just as everything else you do, importing takes time. It also takes memory. There is no need to spend resources on importing something that will not be used. Even if importing one thing is not much, always importing everything (that was your suggestion wasn't it?) would be noticable.